# Simplifying $\left({\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)^2 - \left({\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)^2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi can someone help me please simplify the following showing the working out step by step?

$$
\left({\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)^2 - \left({\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)^2 
$$

I can't get the answer matching the text book but I'd also like to get an idea of the most idiomatic way to solve it in terms of steps.

What I attempt to do based on what I've learned so far is to:

- try and simplify the contents of the parens using conjugate and then LCM
- then square
- then handle the subtraction.

But my answer ends up incorrect.

So even steps just to simplify say the left hand term (without the squaring step) would be helpful.

My simplifying the left hand looks like:

Use Conjugate:

$$
\left(\sqrt{x} + \frac{(1)(\sqrt{x})}{(\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x})}\right)^2
$$

$$
\left(\sqrt{x} + \frac{(\sqrt{x})}{x}\right)^2
$$

Use LCM:

$$
\left(\frac{(\sqrt{x})(x)}{x} + \frac{(\sqrt{x})}{x}\right)^2
$$

$$
\left(\frac{(x)(\sqrt{x}) + \sqrt{x}}{x}\right)^2
$$

Then I'm not sure next best step.

Comment: Use the well-known 'difference of two squares' identity: $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: Or use the binomial expansion $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

Comment: Or use that $$\sqrt{x}\pm\frac1{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{x\pm 1}{\sqrt x}$$

Comment: Use $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2 = 4ab$

Comment: Did you mean $
\left(\dfrac{x\sqrt x + \sqrt{x}}{x}\right)^2
$
 when you typed $
\left(\dfrac{x + \sqrt{x}}{x}\right)^2
$?

Comment: Yep sorry lemme edit

Comment: @J.W.Tanner can you show me how you would simplify from that point? I understand the approach you use with squaring right away is prob the idiomatic approach but I'm trying to use the techniques this text book has covered so far to try and simplify if that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it:

$$
\left({\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)^2 - \left({\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)^2 
$$

$$=\left({ {x} + 2+\frac{1}{ {x}}}\right) - \left(x-2+\frac1x\right)$$

$$=4$$

using $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ with $a=\sqrt x$ and $b=\dfrac1{\sqrt x}$.

**ADDENDUM to answer question in OP's comment**

To start from where you left off,

$$
\left(\frac{x\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x}}{x}\right)^2=\frac {(x\sqrt x+\sqrt x)^2}{x^2}
=\frac{x^3+2x^2+x}{x^2}=x+2+\dfrac1x.$$

Comment: This is what I needed thanks so much for the addendum.

Answer (score 7):

Using $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ we get
$$\left(\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) = \left(2\sqrt{x}\right)\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right) = 4$$
Hence, we get our answer as $4$.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b).$